# How to design layout for 18 inch and above tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, television

I want to create an Application for 18 inch and above tablets in Android, I would like to know few queries as below:

1. What will be the layout, drawable and values folders for the same?
2. Does this come under Tablet or TV?
3. Do I need to check Phone and Tablet or TV, while creating the project?

[image]

Suggestions are strongly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need to develop only for tablets ?

Comment: @SharartiKAKA Yes I want to design it only for tablets which are above 18 inches example: Galaxy View 18.4", Toshiba TT301, ViewSonic VSD241.

Comment: then you have to do it explicitly in Manifest. And yes while uploading on play store account you can restrict there for varity of devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to make your app for tablets you should choose **Phone and Tablet**.

You can restrict your app to only be distributed on a tablet. Like [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps):

```
<manifest ... >
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
...
<application ... >
    ...
</application>
```

But it is recommended that you make your app [support multiple screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)